# Contacts API in Salesforce Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, api

I am trying to use the below api and payload for updating the mobile opt in preference in Salesforce, but I am getting a validation error. Can someone help?

PATCH : https://YOUR_SUBDOMAIN.rest.marketingcloudapis.com/contacts/v1/contacts

payload:

```
{
   "contactKey":"contackey",
   "attributeSets": [{
         "name":"MobileConnect Subscriptions",
         "items": [{
               "values": [
                     { "name":"Keyword", "value":"Addkeyword" },
                      { "name":"Mobile Number", "value":"mobilenumber"},
                     { "name":"Opt In Status", "value":1},
                     { "name":"Opt Out Status", "value":0}
               ]
         }]
   }]
}
```

**Validation Error:**

```
{
    "operationStatus": "FAIL",
    "rowsAffected": 0,
    "contactTypeID": 0,
    "requestServiceMessageID": "4fe9da2d-1408-45a6-90b8-97a6774ffef6",
    "responseDateTime": "2020-09-09T02:14:42.4487199-06:00",
    "hasErrors": true,
    "resultMessages": [
        {
            "resultType": "Validation",
            "resultClass": "Error",
            "resultCode": "InvalidAttributeSet",
            "message": "The Attribute Set [MobileConnect Subscriptions] has validation errors.",
            "innerResultMessages": [
                {
                    "resultType": "Validation",
                    "resultClass": "Error",
                    "resultCode": "RestrictedValueAttribute",
                    "message": "[DefinitionKey: SubscriptionDefinitionID], [DefinitionName: Keyword], [DefinitionID: b1657179-eeef-e911-b82e-b883035b8991] :: The Attribute has a defined set of allowed values. The current value is invalid. [DefinitionName: Keyword], [DefinitionID: b1657179-eeef-e911-b82e-b883035b8991]",
                    "innerResultMessages": []
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "serviceMessageID": "44da64fa-1cb1-4d24-8442-713d72118ed0"
}
```

Comment: for keyword are you passing a value like 'JOIN' or a GUID value?

Comment: I am passing the add keyword that is configured in my mobile connect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the benefit of others, after reaching out to Salesforce, it was understood that the payload needs to be modified in such a way that it either passes the culture code which is required to be 'US' only, or we can pass the created date or modified date in the payload. This is a [know issue](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A0000008gPWQAY&title=unable-to-update-mobileconnect-demographics-values-for-a-contact) in Salesforce.
Also, the value for Opt In needs to be passed as '2', instead of 1. Refer [SMS Subscription Log Data View.](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_data_view_sms_subscription_log.htm&type=5) 
Below is the Sample Payload.

```
    {
   "contactKey":"1234-ABC-456",
   "attributeSets": [{
         "name":"MobileConnect Subscriptions",
         "items": [{
               "values": [
                     { "name":"Keyword", "value":"6B2C6636-6235-4F20-A37DC68FCD1797F2"},
                      { "name":"Mobile Number", "value":"123456789"},
                     { "name":"Opt In Status", "value":2},
                     { "name":"Opt Out Status", "value":0},
                     {"name":"Modified Date", "value": "2020-09-22 10:00:03"}, 
                    {"name":"Created Date", "value": "2020-09-22 10:00:03"} 

               ]
         }]
   }]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The value of Keyword must be the KeywordID (it will be a 32 character key) - you can get it querying the Data View _SMSMessageTracking, like this:

select KeywordID from _SMSMessageTracking where Mobile = 'XXXXXXXXXX'

More details here: https://code4.cloud/articles/sfmc-unsubscribe-mobile-numbers-at-keyword-level-mobileconnect/

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you @Anderson for your reply .However, the issue still persist. It seems that it is an internal salesforce error. https://trailblazers.salesforce.com/answers?id=9063A000000DqsYQAS.  I have raised a case with SF, will keep you posted.