# SFMC - Update failed for one or more AttributeSets - Rest API to /contacts/v1/contacts endpoint

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketingcloudapi

I'm getting an error message when using an API to the /contacts/v1/contacts endpoint.

Error message is: Update failed for one or more AttributeSets. Note: Updates aren't allowed on attributes that form the primary Key of the attributeset

and here's the payload:

```
{
  "contactKey": "1234567",
  "attributeSets": [
    {
      "name": "MobileConnect Subscriptions",
      "items": [
        {
          "values": [
            {
              "name": "Keyword",
              "value": "3b234c69-d2a3-45a6-8826-a03b76311124"
            },
            {
              "name": "Mobile Number",
              "value": "4671234567"
            },
            {
              "name": "Opt In Status",
              "value": "2"
            },
            {
              "name": "Opt Out Status",
              "value": "0"
            },
            {
              "name": "Modified Date",
              "value": "2023-06-28 05:14:26"
            },
            {
              "name": "Created Date",
              "value": "2023-06-28 05:14:26"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I tried using the keywordID from the SMSSubscriptions log however I got an error related to the key, so am now using the JOIN keyword ID.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/319168/contacts-api-in-salesforce-marketing-cloud

Comment: Thanks Rachid, unfortunately not - I'd seen that post and am passing created date and modified date in CST.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out for the Patch method you need to remove the Mobile Number from the payload. Here's the payload and script I used:

```
var keywordid = "134"
var opt_in_status = 2;
var opt_out_status = 0;

var payload = '{';
payload += '"contactKey":"' + subscriberkey + '",';
payload += '"attributeSets": [{';
payload += '"name": "MobileConnect Subscriptions",';
payload += '"items": [{';
payload += '"values": [';
payload += '{ "name": "Keyword", "value":"' + keywordid + '"},';
payload += '{ "name": "Opt In Status", "value":"' + opt_in_status + '"},';
payload += '{ "name": "Opt Out Status", "value":' + opt_out_status + '},';
payload += '{ "name": "Modified Date", "value":"' + formattedTimestamp + '"},';
payload += '{ "name": "Created Date", "value":"' + formattedTimestamp + '"}';
payload += ']';
payload += '}]';
payload += '}]';
payload += '}';
}

var auth = 'Bearer ' + accessToken;

var req = new Script.Util.HttpRequest(url);
    req.emptyContentHandling = 0;
    req.retries = 2;
    req.continueOnError = true;
    req.contentType = "application/json"
    req.setHeader("Authorization", auth);
    req.method = "PATCH";
    req.postData = payload;

  var resp = req.send();

  var resultString = String(resp.content);
  var resultJSON = Platform.Function.ParseJSON(String(resp.content));

  Write(Stringify(resultJSON))
```